# Top row of Dataframe got printed over and over again in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tfidfvectorizer

I'm using a large database as input. I've tried two different methods but both got me the same result with the top row printed for every loop.

I'm not sure what I did wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated.

My code

```
def cal_score(search_word):
    for file in files:
      with open(catcal_dir + file, "r") as infile:
        content = json.load(infile)
        if word in content["Convo"]:
          convo_content = content["Convo"]

          vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words = {'english'}, ngram_range=(1,3), lowercase=True)
          tfidf_print = vectorizer.fit_transform([convo_content])
          feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
          feature_index = tfidf_print[0,:].nonzero()[1]
          tfidf_scores = zip(feature_index, [tfidf_print[0, x] for x in feature_index])

          data = {}
          for word, score in [(feature_names[i], score) for (i, score) in tfidf_scores]:
            if search_word == word:
              data['Score'] = score
              data['Date'] = content['Date']
              data['Term'] = word

          df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Date', 'Score', 'Term'], index=[0])
          print(df)

print(cal_score('nekko'))
```

Output I got

```
           Date     Score       Term
0  May 16, 1797  0.002463  nekko
             Date     Score       Term
0  March 04, 1809  0.005918  nekko
            Date     Score       Term
0  July 09, 1812  0.019306  nekko
             Date     Score       Term
0  March 04, 1813  0.006175  nekko
            Date     Score       Term
0  July 23, 1813  0.008521  nekko
```

The output I want

```
           Date     Score       Term
0  May 16, 1797  0.002463  nekko
1  March 04, 1809  0.005918  nekko
2 July 09, 1812  0.019306  nekko
3  March 04, 1813  0.006175  nekko
4  July 23, 1813  0.008521  nekko
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating one dataframe for each file in your database and then printing the result. You probably want to gather the data from each file first, then create and print the dataframe once at the end.

Comment: Hi. I thought I've gathered them in the data variable? Because when I print the key and values in data, it shows al the data I gathered.

Comment: You assign `data = {}` within the `for file in files` loop and then create a dataframe from that `data` variable. If you want to include all the data from all of the files in one dataframe, you can't overwrite the `data` variable on each pass through the loop.